# TextView don't fire first click

Tags: android, button, textview, onclicklistener

I have a TextView that which should be clicked like a button.

Here is the code:

```html
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/play"
        style="@style/playButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/homePlay"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Now when I click on it, it doesn't work for first time, but subsequent clicks are working fine.

Here is the Java Code:

```js
TextView play = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.play);
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View view) {
                      System.out.println("------------CLICKED");
                  }
              });
          }
        });
```

The "------------CLICKED" is shown just when clicking for 2nd time etc. not at the first time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a nested onClickListener. 
Remove the innermost one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove nested **`setOnClickListener`** from your `play.setOnClickListener`

```
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              System.out.println("------------CLICKED");
          }
        });
```

Comment: What a mistake Thank you very Much

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code snippet as below, and check.

XML(Focus setting is removed)

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/play"
        style="@style/playButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/homePlay"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

JAVA CODE(Nested setOnClickListener is removed)

```
TextView play = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.play);
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              System.out.println("------------CLICKED");
          }
        });
```